# angular class method not working when populated by service

Tags: angular, class, typescript, methods

I'm learning Angular 4 and I can't figure out how to get class methods to work.

I have a class for the feature, that includes some methods that allow constructing a google charts JSON datatable.

```
export class Feature {
    id: string;
    name: string;

    get cols() {
        return [
        {'id': '', 'label': 'id', 'type': 'string'},
        {'id': '', 'label': 'name', 'type': 'string'}
        ];
    }

    get row() {
        console.log('foo');
        return {'c': [ {'v': this.id}, {'v': this.name} ] };
    }

}
```

I have a service that populates the features from a REST API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Feature } from './feature';

@Injectable()
export class FeatureService {
  private featureUrl = 'http://raspi/rest/api';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getFeatures(): Promise<Feature[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.featureUrl + '/getFeatures')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().results as Feature[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

Then in my component, on init, I call the service, and attempt to convert the instance array into a Google datatable:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Feature } from '../feature';
import { FeatureService } from '../feature.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-features',
  templateUrl: './features.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./features.component.css']
})
export class FeaturesComponent implements OnInit {
  features: Feature[];

  public tableData = {
    chartType: 'Table',
    dataTable: {},
    options: {'title': 'Tasks'},
  };

  constructor(
    private featureService: FeatureService
  ) { }

  private features2dataTable(features: Feature[]) {
    const data = {
      'cols': [],
      'rows': []
    }

    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      console.log(feature);
      data.cols = feature.cols;
      data.rows.push( feature.row );
    });
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }

  getFeatures(): void {
    this.featureService
      .getFeatures()
      .then(features => this.tableData.dataTable = this.features2dataTable(features))
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFeatures();
  }

}
```

I want the datatable to have this format:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

but when I use feature.row or feature.cols, I get back undefined, even though the "id" and "name" fields of the instance are populated:

```
{id: "BP01", name: "BP feature one"}
   id: "BP01"
   name: "BP feature one"
   __proto__: Object
    features.component.ts:30 

{id: "BP02", name: "BP feature two"}
   id: "BP02"
   name: "BP feature two"
   __proto__: Object
    features.component.ts:34

{cols: undefined, rows: Array(2)}
   cols: undefined
   rows: (2) [undefined, undefined]
   __proto__: Object
```

Why won't the get method work?

Comment: why are you doing this in same line separate it `this.tableData.dataTable = this.features2dataTable(features)`. can you show how features looks when comming from database

Comment: Could it be that the response you're getting does not conform with the Class definition you're expecting? What is the result of console.log(response.json())  please?

Comment: Sorry, the "id" and "name" fields were correctly being populated.  This was visible when I do the console.log(feature) inside of my features.forEach loop.  The problem is that each feature only had the "id" and "name" fields, and did not have the "row" or "cols" methods that were defined in the class.

AJT_82 Identified the problem.  I was looping on POJOs instead of Feature objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing...

```
.then(response => response.json().results as Feature[])
```

does not actually create an array of `Feature` objects, therefore you do not have access to any class specific methods, since they are just POJO's.

You need to explicitly make the objects instances of your class, so something like this:

```
getFeatures() {
  return this.http.get(this.featureUrl + '/getFeatures')
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().results.map(obj => Object.assign(new Feature(), obj)))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved my problem.  This seems very counter-intuitive for me.  When following the angular.io/tutorial it seems implied that you create a Hero class to store Hero objects.  What is the purpose of importing the class and using it in the "as Feature[]" if the class just gets ignored and a POJO gets returned?

Comment: Well what is going on in the tuto is **type assertion**. We just tell the compiler that we know how our data looks like. you can read here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html :)

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that you need to define both a setter and a getter:

```
export class Feature {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    private _cols;

    get cols() {
        return this._cols;
    }

    set cols() {
        this._cols = [
        {'id': '', 'label': 'id', 'type': 'string'},
        {'id': '', 'label': 'name', 'type': 'string'}
        ];
    }

    /** 
      Same as above for rows
    */

}
```

However, this might not be correct, since you're using a class as a type here - on your console.log @ line 30, you're only getting out col data, and not the entire row? Seems like you're not getting the correct data.

You want something like this:

```
[
  {
    cols: [...],
    row: {...}
  }
]
```

but you're getting:

```
[
 {...} // col & row data
]
```

Try doing a console.log on the features passed in to the features2datatable function, and this should steer you in the right direction :)