# angular class functions not working/available when service response is assigned to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have a below class `Invoice` with some data and methods in it but when I assign REST API array response to my component class array I observe that angular `Invoice` class methods like **addItem**, **removeItem** are not available.

I've tried this [angular class method not working when populated by service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727086/angular-class-method-not-working-when-populated-by-service) but did not work for me.

Have a look at the below code,

**`1. Invoice class (angular class)`**

```js
import { Customer } from "./customer";
import { InvoiceItem } from "./invoice_item";
import { Item } from "./item";

export class Invoice {
    invoiceId?: number;
    invoiceNumber: number;
    
    customer: Customer;
    invoiceItem: InvoiceItem[] = [];

    constructor(customer?: Customer, invoiceNumber?: number) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        this.invoiceItem.push({itemId: 0, quantity: 0, rate: 0}); // default invoice_item
    }

    addItem() {
        this.invoiceItem.push({itemId: 0, quantity: 0, rate: 0}); // default invoice_item
    }

    removeItem(item) {
        this.invoiceItem.splice(this.invoiceItem.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
    
}
```

**`2. Component Class(angular)`**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/model/customer';
import { Invoice } from 'src/app/model/invoice';
import { InvoiceService } from 'src/app/services/invoice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-invoices',
  templateUrl: './admin-invoices.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-invoices.component.css']
})
export class AdminInvoicesComponent {
  customerInvoices: Invoice[] = [];
  customerId: number; 

 
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
              private invoiceService: InvoiceService) {
    this.customerId = (this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('customerId'));

     this.invoiceService.getCustomerInvoices(this.customerId)
      .subscribe((invoices: Invoice[]) => {
        this.customerInvoices = invoices; // assigning service response
      });
  }

}
```

**In the below image you can see service response.** Also, we can see the `**constructor**` of type **`Object`** instead of type `**Invoice**` even if we have declared our `customerInvoices` array of type Invoice as `customerInvoices: Invoice[] = [];` in our component class.

[image: service-response]

**Expected Output is as below:**

[image: expected-output]

**Service Class Code:**

```js
 getCustomerInvoices(custId: number) {
    const currentUser = this.authService.currentUserValue;
    const headers = {'x-auth-token': currentUser.token};

    return this.httpClient.get(environment.apiUrl +"/api/invoices/customer/" +custId, {headers})
      .pipe(map((invoices) => {
        return invoices;
      }));
  }
```

Comment: Please share your service class code which makes API call.

Comment: @VimalPatel provided you with the service class code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it's clear that the service is returning plain objects, not instances of `Invoice`. If you want them to be instances of `Invoice`, you'll need to construct those instances (either in the service or in the receiving class) rather than constructing blank objects.

For instance, if you do it in the receiving class:

```
this.invoiceService.getCustomerInvoices(this.customerId)
.subscribe((invoices: Invoice[]) => {
    this.customerInvoices = invoices.map(invoice => new Invoice(invoice));
})
```

...and update `Invoice`'s constructor to support passing in a raw invoice object and grabbing its fields. Something along these lines:

```
constructor(customer?: Customer, invoiceNumber?: number);
constructor(invoice: Invoice);
constructor(customerOrInvoice?: Customer | Invoice, invoiceNumber?: number) {
    if ("customer" in customerOrInvoice) {
        // Either `Object.assign` to copy everything:
        // Object.assign(this, customerOrInvoice);
        // ...or do it explicitly, which will make the TypeScript compiler happier
        // because all branches will definitely assign to the properties:
        this.customer = customerOrInvoice.customer;
        this.invoiceNumber = customerOrInvoice.invoiceNumber;
        this.invoiceItem = customerOrInvoice.invoiceItem;
        // Note: The above assumes it's okay to reuse the array of invoice items
        // and the invoice items inside it. If it isn't, copy it:
        // this.invoiceItem = customerOrInvoice.invoiceItem.slice();
        // If it isn't okay to reuse the invoice items inside it, copy them too:
        // this.invoiceItem = customerOrInvoice.invoiceItem.map(item => ({...item}));
    } else {
        this.customer = customerOrInvoice;
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        this.invoiceItem.push({itemId: 0, quantity: 0, rate: 0}); // default invoice_item
    }
}
```

Note that like all [overloaded functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), only the two overload signatures will be available to code outside the class; the third one is purely an implementation signature.

Comment: the approach you've shown is 1 way of doing it but the problem I see here is, let's assume if a customer has 1000 or more invoices under it and every time we fetch the list of all invoices under a customer, that many instances of **`Invoice`** class will get created **(either in the service or in the receiving class)** which will potentially have an effect on performance. **So, can we think of any other way by looking at the service class code above?**

Comment: @RupeshBharuka - 1,000 or even a million invoices is nothing to be concerned about, not even on a mobile device. In your current code you're reusing the invoice item array, so all we have to copy is the invoice itself. That's very fast, [try it here](https://output.jsbin.com/faxunokoja/1). My iPhone is happy to do a million of those invoices in 50ms. Maybe a slow smartphone might take five times that long -- a quarter of a second. :-) And that's a million. But if copying the invoice objects is a problem, don't use an `Invoice` class, use standalone functions you pass the invoice objects into.

Comment: I'm really thankful to you for all your time & efforts in this query. What you've shown above is really cool and acceptable :-)